# Retrieving list items from multiple sites via OData with Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-services, powerpivot, odata

I want to build a report:

- with Excel 2013 + PowerPivot Add-In
- using data from SharePoint Online
- that should work in Excel Services (so I'm not able to use VB, Power Query, etc.)

Report should be build against list items stored on multiple sub sites of a site collection.

For example, here is a root site:

```
http://<root>
```

that have the following sub sites:

```
http://<root>/siteA
http://<root>/siteB
...
http://<root>/siteZ
```

each of these sites has a list **CustomItems**. I need to retrieve all the items from **CustomItems** lists in Excel.

It looks that items can be retrieved with the OData query like:

```
http://<root>/_api/Web/Webs?$expand=Lists/Items
```

but if I add this query as Data Source, Excel extracts only **Webs** items, but doesn't extract **Lists** or **Items** expanded in the request.

Is there a way to retrieve these items in Excel?

Comment: I have a similar requirement... could you please share your approach...

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't find a solution yet. It seems that it is not possible to resolve that for the moment...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this as a single request, then I suggest you take a look at the search API.

The way you are doing it, won't be manageable, if possible at all unless you are able to do it with Macros and an iterative approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Using this you can filter by URL, Current Site, Site Collection and Web application amongst many other things, make sure the field you want is indexed and retrievable:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667%28v=office.15%29.aspx

And you will be able to query very easily the data you require.

The downside is waiting for the item to be crawled, but the delay in this is often not more than 15 minutes with SharePoint 2013, due to incremental crawl.

Comment: I cannot use macro as report should work in Excel Services and I don't have any idea how to implement iterative approach without it. Search approach doesn't work as well as Excel doesn't accept search feed as data source.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this so many times and also always wanted to know if there was a way.  Craig Tarr wrote up a way on how to do it using front-end code.  Basically the script structures unstructured data using REST API.  Once you have the data you can export to excel or another DB.  Completely configurable.

https://www.gtconsult.com/extracting-unstructured-data-that-should-be-structured/

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers. This answer is the same as http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163313/export-mulltiple-lists-onto-same-sheet-in-excel/197273#197273 If the questions are the same we should close one as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Can you replace the Webs in `http://<root>/_api/Web/**Webs**/GetByTitle('list-name')/ItemsItems` with the lists word. I think that should solve your problem.

Also have a look on [Basic operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for retrieving data using REST interface in SharePoint.

For operation with subsites `http://<root>/subsite/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('list-name')/Items`.
sample: using get operation.

`url: http://site-url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘CustomList')/items
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"`

**site-url = root/sub-site**

For more details have a look at this [diagram](http://zoom.it/Z9oC#full).
[image: SharePoint Rest Api Diagram]

Comment: This wouldn't work, because Web/Lists returns lists on current site, but not from the sub sites.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can use 
`http://<root>/subsite/_api/web/lists?$expand=Lists/Items`.

Comment: As I said, this doesn't work, since  it doesn't return neither sub site lists nor list items.

Comment: Let me know if this serves your problem: `http://site-url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘CustomItems')/items`.

Comment: Again, I need to retrieve items from **lists located on sub sites.** The way you propose returns list items **only from root site.**

Comment: Modify your site-url, as I already mentioned it and have given you sufficient references. NOTE: if you need to deal with subsite just append the subsite with subsite name. Also the rest based api is always scoped at site level, and so there is no specific way other than this atleast as per docs. Also do check my modified answers again, i have even added samples. And if you dont believe my answer kindly go and check ms documentation on the above.